# Formula of second derivative for differential equation y'=f(x,y)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

In the textbook Ordinary Differential Equations by Tenenbaum and Pollard, Lesson 45 on improvement of polygonal starting method P641:

Let $y(x)$ be a particular solution:

$y' = f(x,y)$

It says on P642 that "By differentiation of the above formula, we assume the derivatives exist-we obtain"

$y'' = \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx}$

Question is how did the author reach to this formula with $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: This link could be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1566376/874549

Comment: Chain rule. ${}$